# create hot keys in java using swing

Tags: java, swing

Hi I wrote the following code to create hot keys in java Swing. I create the Mnemonic for `Jtextfield1 (Name)`. It showed properly, but now I need to know if at run time I immediately click `tf2` then the cursor will come to `tf2` from `tf1`.

I enter some values in `tf2`. Then I need to enter `tf1`. In this situation I press `ALT+N` keys (because N is mnemonic of `tf1`). The cursor focused `tf1` and entered the name in the textfield. how do I do this?

```
package hotkeys;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

public class hotkey extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {

        JLabel Name=new JLabel("Name");
        JTextField tf1=new JTextField(20);
        Name.setLabelFor( Name );
        Name.setDisplayedMnemonic( 'N' );

        JLabel Regno=new JLabel("Reg_NO");
        JTextField tf2=new JTextField(20);

        JButton b1=new JButton("Save");
        JButton b2=new JButton("eXit");

        JFrame f=new JFrame();
        JPanel p=new JPanel();

        p.add(Name);
        p.add(Regno);
        p.add(tf1);
        p.add(tf2);
        p.add(b1);
        p.add(b2);

        f.add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.pack();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to look for [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), output from `KeyBindings` should be [javax.swing.Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and there you can wrap set `Focus` to the decisions `JComponent`,

Answer (score 1):

The need you describe is a mnemonic for JTextField. For AbstractButton derivatives you set mnemonic directly with [setMnemonic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMnemonic%28int%29). For JTextField you create a JLabel and set the mnemonic to JLabel. Then you attach the label to the text field and the mnemonic works as expected. You attach the label to the text field like this:

```
label.setLabelFor(textField);
```

So the only thing wrong in your code is that you entered wrong argument in the call to [setLabelFor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setLabelFor%28java.awt.Component%29).